# test-connection that supports wildcard? workaround?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

trying to see if anyone has a known workaround for using the test-connection cmdlet in powershell to ping wildcard entries in DNS.

I'm trying to clean out our DNS db and exported a list from our BIND server and am in the process of just pinging through the 600+ machines to see if anything responds. I made my own simple script but have also found one that works slightly better on this forum. The script works but the cmdlet help files state that the -computername parameter does not support wildcards and sure enough, when i run the script all CNAME records are reporting down/false when they actually should be responding. The code I'm using is below and is kind of messy but I just needed something quick and it works, but I've included it below for reference:

```
Get-Content -path C:\Work\testy.txt  | ForEach-Object { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -AsJob } | Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait | Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_.Address}},@{Name='Reachable';Expression={if ($_.StatusCode -eq 0) { $true } else { $false }}} |out-file -FilePath c:\work\TEST.txt
```

Comment: Since it's a wildcard record, you can substitute any label. `"*.domain.tld" -replace '\*','wildcard'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen not _any_ label, because if it exists as a real record you'll be pinging something else. But you could choose something that's very unlikely to have been used before..

Comment: thanks guys. I'll give that a try and see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed out by briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186865/test-connection-that-supports-wildcard-workaround/36187025#comment60009209_36186865), any non-existing record name will do. You could generate a GUID to substitute the `*` in your record name:

```
"subdomain.domain.tld","*.domain.tld" |ForEach-Object {
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $($_ -replace '\*',"$([guid]::NewGuid())")
}
```

Your expression for whether it's "Reachable" or not can be simplified as well:

```
@{Name='Reachable'; Expression={[bool]($_.StatusCode -eq 0)}}
```